# How to rebind Home and End keys in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: macos, ubuntu, keymapping

Hello I am trying rebind End and Home to CTRL+Right, CTRL+Left (like Mac Os). I am tried with xmodmap like this

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 113 = Left NoSymbol Home'
```

But this is set Left arrow to Home (without CTRL)...

I have also rebinded some keys via Tweak tool (ctrl alt super). When I run command xmodmap I get list of rebinded keys but can't see my new bind with Left arrow.

```
shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x40),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x85),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)  
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x25),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

Is there some chance to have only one file with all my custom rebinds and this file connecting to xmodmap while starting Ubuntu?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Best to ask this on SuperUser or the Unix stack exchange. Off-topic for Stack Overflow, unfortunately.

Comment: maybe helps [https://superuser.com/questions/412295/enable-ctrl-or-alt-arrow-keys-to-mimic-home-and-end-functionality](https://superuser.com/questions/412295/enable-ctrl-or-alt-arrow-keys-to-mimic-home-and-end-functionality)